# Wrong parameter passed into URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb

Trying to link to the "user_annversary_path" and the incorrect anniversary path is being passed in. user_id is correct (2) but id (for the anniversary) should be 1.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AnniversaryController#show

Couldn't find Anniversary with id=2
Rails.root: /Users/nelsonkeating/Desktop/ReminDeal

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/anniversary_controller.rb:10:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"user_id"=>"2",
 "id"=>"2"}
```

anniversary_controller

```
  def show 
      @user = current_user
      @anniversary = Anniversary.find(params[:id])
    end
```

View code triggering the incorrect paramater being passed in

```
<%= link_to "Anniversary", user_anniversary_path(@user) %>
```

Routes

```
  resources :users do
      resources :anniversary
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

For the `user_anniversary_path`, you need to be passing in *two* arguments: a `User` object (or an id that represents a `User` object) and an `Anniversary` object (or an id that represents an `Anniversary` object). For example, you can do this:

```
user_anniversary_path(User.first, Anniversary.first)
```

Or this:

```
user_anniversary_path(1, 2)
```

Where `1` is the `id` of the `User` object, and `2` is the `id` of the `Anniversary` object. I would really recommend sticking with passing in whole objects to this method.

The reason why it's failing when you try Trent's example is because `@anniversary` is nil in the action that you're calling that routing helper in. Just be careful regarding that.

Comment: @ryan-brigg thanks for the answer but still a little confused as to how i should alter my link_to path... I essentially need to search my anniversaries table based off of the user_id.. (has_many : anniversaries, belongs_to :user association).

Answer (score 0):

Is anniversary nested within user in your routes.rb? If so, try passing in the Anniversary with the user.

```
<%= link_to "Anniversary", user_anniversary_path(@user, @anniversary) %>
```

Also, why not just pass in the current_user from the view? Is it not accessible?

```
<%= link_to "Anniversary", user_anniversary_path(current_user, @anniversary) %>
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources for more details.

Comment: yes, @trent it is nested (i added routing above). Both your error trigger a routing error.. see gist https://gist.github.com/2922180

Comment: Check out Ryan's answer below. I wrongly assumed you were working in a view that had an @anniversary instance variable.

Comment: I just read your comment on Ryan's post. It looks like you're needing the user_anniversaries_path(User.first). Or current_user if accessible within the view.

Comment: not following.. i need /users/2/anniversary/1 as my url.. The first user did not have an anniversary.. The second user did.

Comment: solved it with : <%= link_to "Anniversary", @user.anniversaries %>

Comment: Ok great. I thought I was misunderstanding you. Glad you got it working!